# How to pass input data back to class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

How can I pass data from both input selects in my child component, to my parent component state which is a class component?

Scratching my head on this one.

**Parent Component**

```
export default class ProfileEditor extends React.Component<IProfileEditorProps, IProfileEditorState> {

  constructor(props: IProfileEditorProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      currentUser: null,
      select1: values to be set from child component
      select2: values to be set from child component
    }
        <MultiSelect
            options={countries}
            onInputChange1={input1 => console.log(input1)}
            onInputChange2={input2 => console.log(input2)}
          />
```

**Child Component:**

```
export const MultiSelect = ({options, onInputChange1, onInputChange2}) => {

  console.log(options);

  const [options1, setOption1] = React.useState(options);
  const [options2, setOption2] = React.useState(options);
  
  return (
    <>
      <Select
        isMulti
        options={options1}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        onInputChange={onInputChange1} 
        onChange={(v1) => {
          setOption2(options.filter((o2) => !v1.includes(o2)));
        }}
      />
      <div style={{ height: 30 }} />
      <Select
        isMulti
        options={options2}
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        onInputChange={onInputChange2}
        onChange={(v2) => {
          setOption1(options.filter((o1) => !v2.includes(o1)));
        }} 
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a callback from the parent to the child. In the child, define some props to allow the parent to pass the callback to so it can listen to the input change:

```
export const MultiSelect = ({ onInputChange1, onInputChange2 }) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Select
          {...}
          onInputChange={onInputChange1}
        />
        <div style={{ height: 30 }} />
        <Select
          {...}
          onInputChange={onInputChange2}
        />
      </>
    );
  };
```

In the parent, you can start listening and do whatever you want when the input value changes:

```
<MultiSelect onInputChange1={input1 => {...}} onInputChange2={input2 => {...}} />
```

Comment: I have made edits to the original question, I have followed this design pattern but I am console logging blanks when making selections on the inputs

Comment: @BennKingy but it works in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/69649548-using-react-select-how-can-i-filter-the-dropdown-options-between-2-selects-forked-tduuq?file=/example.tsx) codesandbox.

Comment: It seems to be console logging an empty string in the codesandbox?

Comment: @BennKingy it does capture the input value when the use types in the input field. If you want to know when the user selects an option, use `onChange` instead.

Comment: @NearlHuscarl Gotcha! Thank you so much I feel like I much better understand react now :D